# Kernel and Range of a Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am lost on this problem. It asks

```
 "Consider the following linear transformation T : P2 -> P2 defined 
  by T(ax^2+bx+c) = ax^2 + (a+2b+c)x + (3a-2b-c)" 
  where a,b,c are arbitrary constants.
        a) Show that Ker(T) consists of all polynomials of the form b(x-2), 
                 and hence, find its dimension.
        b) Find Rng(T) and its dimension.
```

So far, I got this, and I don't know if this is correct or even what to do next. If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

This is my work so far:

```
 dim(p2)=3
 Ker(t) = {ax^2+bx+c : T(ax^2+bx+c)=0; a,b,c in the set of reals}
 Ker(t) = {ax^2+bx+c : ax^2 + (a+2b+c)x + (3a-2b-c) = 0 ; a,b,c in the set of reals}
 ax^2+(a+2b+c)x+(3a-2b-c)=0 for all x in the set of real numbers
 so, a=0, a+2b+c=0, and 3a-2b-c=0 
    -> a=0, b=(-1/2)c, c=-2b
```

Comment: Your calculation is correct. For finding the range I suggest you look at what $T$ does to $x^2$ and $x$ and $1$. As a rule of thumb it is always best if you start investigating what happens to the basis.

Comment: I'm glad to know I was correct up to that point, but next should I just load the numbers in front of a, b, and c into a matrix along with a 0-column and row-reduce to find the kernel?

Comment: You've already found the kernel. If $a=0$ and $c=-2b$ then $Ker T = \{b(x-2)|b\in \mathbb{R}\}$ as you've found and as the question asks you to prove.

Comment: So when I calculated the range, all I seem to come up with is that the monomials containing "c" get left out and that's it. Leaving me with the result that the rng(T) = span{(a)x^2+(a+2b)x+(3a-2b)}. I got this by trying the usual thing, which is putting them in a matrix and finding the pivot columns.

Comment: Actually it seems that the range would be rng(T) ={(a, a+2b, 3a-2b) : a and b are within the set of reals}, but I'm not quite sure if thats right in this polynomial formed question